# Pause on the first frame before scroll on a ffmpeg script generated video

Tags: shell, video, scroll, ffmpeg

I need to put a 2 seconds initial pause on the first frame before starting to scroll in the video generated by this script:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1200x1200 -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i cut.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1200:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=30[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.01':eof_action=endall[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```

I use it to create a vertical scrolling video of my website full screen snapshot.

I tried everythingh but I can't find the solution.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift all output timestamps by 2 seconds. FFmpeg will clone the first frame to fill the gap from time 0 to the shifted timestamp of the first frame.

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1200x1200 -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i cut.png -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1200:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=30[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-'t*h*0.01':eof_action=endall,setpts=PTS+2/TB[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4`

Comment: You are my hero :)